# i want display, javascript via URL

Tags: javascript, java, html, node.js, ajax

I want to display this but it's not working help me.

```
document.write('<a href="/site"><img src="" alt="image"/></a> var answer = 
confirm ("Please click on OK to continue loading my page, or CANCEL to be 
directed to the Yahoo site.")
if (answer)
    window.location="https://www.google.co.in";');
```

Answer (score 0):

Document and script are so different.
If you open confirm when accessthe page, you can this.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var answer = confirm ("Please click on OK to continue loading my page, or CANCEL to be directed to the Yahoo site.");
        if (answer) window.location="https://www.google.co.in";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: but i want load that script like this <script type="text/javascript" src="/url"></script>

Comment: @andro sorry. I don't understand your word

Comment: @andro... Do you mean you want to load script from a URL?? Or do you want to load script from a locally stored JS file in your machine?

Comment: i want load as a url

Comment: i want disply some texts also via that script

Comment: @andro... But why do you need that?? Well, You can do that, just add proper URL instead of location.. and it will do that....... But make sure, it will take the source code that mean HTML formatting will destroy JS script

Comment: i ts for displying some ads to difrent sites